# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. - Json

Tags: c#, json

Segue código:

```
public class Name
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Items
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hobbies
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public Items items { get; set; }
    }

    public class Properties
    {
        public Name name { get; set; }
        public Hobbies hobbies { get; set; }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public Properties properties { get; set; }
    }
```

Estou tentando serializar assim:

```
Example model = new Example();
model.properties.name.type = "cc";
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
```

Recebo erro:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

O erro ocorre na linha: `model.properties.name.type = "cc";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suas classes tem propriedades que são do tipo complexo (`classes`) então precisam ser instanciadas, para que você tenha acesso as suas propriedades mais internas, olha as mudanças:

```
public class Name
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{   
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Hobbies
{
    public Hobbies()
    {
        items = new Items();
    }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Items items { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public Properties()
    {
        hobbies = new Hobbies();
        name = new Name(); 
    }
    public Name name { get; set; }
    public Hobbies hobbies { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public Example()
    {
        properties = new Properties();
    }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Properties properties { get; set; }
}
```

A sequencia seria no *construtor* de `Hobbies` instanciar `Items`, no *construtor* de `Properties` é instanciado `Hobbies` e `Name` e por fim dentro do *construtor* `Example` é instanciado `Properties`.

[Projeto ONLine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BOcHVI)

Se por ventura não quiser fazer assim, após instanciar `Example` se pode instanciar as classes também, mas, acredito que a forma que te passei é a ideal, se for utilizar todo esse código, um exemplo com um outra forma de trabalhar com essas instâncias:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Name
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{   
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Hobbies
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Items items { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{   
    public Name name { get; set; }
    public Hobbies hobbies { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Properties properties { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Example model = new Example();
        model.properties = new Properties();
        model.properties.name = new Name();
        model.properties.hobbies = new Hobbies();
        model.properties.hobbies.items = new Items();
        model.properties.name.type = "cc";
        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        System.Console.WriteLine(data);
    }
}
```

[Projeto OnLine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/57HC5w)

Comment: Agora entendi onde eu errei, obrigado Virgilio :)

Answer (score 1):

O problema é porque dentro da classe Example, você tem uma outra classe com o nome
de properties, e você apenas instânciou a classe Example, mas também teria que instanciar a properties depois para poder usá-la, exemplo:

```
Example model = new Example();
model.properties = new Properties();
model.properties.name.type = "cc";
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
```

Você pode instânciar na mão assim, ou então no construtor da classe example, você coloca para instânciar a properties, pode deixar sua classe Example conforme abaixo e seu código vai funcionar:

```
public class Example
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Properties properties { get; set; }

    public Example()
    {
       properties = new Properties();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não seria um erro no nome da classe?

```
public class Propertie
{
    public Name name { get; set; }
    public Hobbies hobbies { get; set; }
}
```

Está declarada como Propertie, mas você tenta acessar como Properties.

Entendi, analisei o código e percebi que você está tentando acessar propriedades que não existem.

```
Example model = new Example();
model.properties.name.type = "cc";
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
```

Observe o código acima. Na linha do erro, a classe Properties não tem a propriedade type na propriedade name. Não seria apenas model.properties.type = "cc"?

Comment: "Json.Propertie" não contém uma definição para "type"

Comment: Desculpe, seria model.type;

Comment: Não funcionou, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Por nada! Sempre que precisar!